# Leaflet - two colors same path

Tags: leaflet, openlayers

Wanted to know if is there a way to get a single path (line) to have 2 colors?

for example one next to each other[image: Example]

I want to display 2 different paths (multi poly-lines) at same times, and each one of them has different color, but somethings they share similar path.

Comment: There's an old question with a working solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610351/stacked-lines-or-multilines-between-two-points-on-map
The jsfiddle works when the outdated ol.js and ol.css links are replaced by working links from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/openlayers/3.10.1

Comment: See also https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineOffset